# how to get and admin name in backend in magento 2

Tags: php, database, backend, magento2.2

I have created **admin grid and associated form**. In that, If I **add a new item** the **time** and **date** is **automatically saved**.  But the **name** of **who** is **added** the **item** and **who** is **edited** the item is also need to be save in DB.How to **retrieve** these things and  **dispaly** it in **Backend** ?  Please suggest me a solution ...
Thanks in advance.

I have created below files to display it

**xxx\HomeSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\AdditionalInfo.php**

```
<?php

namespace xxx\HomeSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use xxx\HomeSlider\Model\Post;

class AdditionalInfo extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

    /**
     * Interval in minutes that shows how long customer will be marked 'Online'
     * since his last activity. Used only if it's impossible to get such setting
     * from configuration.
     */
    const DEFAULT_ONLINE_MINUTES_INTERVAL = 15;

    protected $dateTime;


    protected $coreRegistry;
    protected $authSession;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime, \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession, array $data = []
    )
    {

        $this->authSession = $authSession;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentUser()
    {
        return $this->authSession->getUser();
    }

}
```

**Additionalinfo.phtml**

```
 <?php
    $adminName = $block->getCurrentUser();

    ?>
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper customer-information">
        <div class="fieldset-wrapper-title">
            <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Additional Information')) ?></span>
        </div>
        <table class="admin__table-secondary">
            <tbody>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
                <tr>
                    <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Created At:')) ?></th>
                    <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($adminName) ?></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>
    <?php
```

Controller file **save.php**

```
<?php

namespace OX\HomeSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $postModel = $this->_objectManager->create('OX\HomeSlider\Model\Post');

        if ($id) {
            $postModel = $postModel->load($id);
        }
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getParam('general');
        if (empty($post['id'])) {
            $post['id'] = null;
        }

        if (isset($post['image'])) {
            $post['image'] = $post['image'][0]['name'];
        } else {
            $post['image'] = null;
        }


        $postModel->setData($post);
        $postModel->save();
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('homeslider/post/index');
    }

}
```

Controller for **edit.php**

```
<?php
namespace OX\HomeSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;
class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_resultPage;
    protected $_resultPageFactory = false;
    protected $_coreRegistry;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory, \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $post = $this->_objectManager->create('OX\HomeSlider\Model\Post');
        if ($id) {
            $post = $post->load($id);
            if ($post->getId()) {
                $this->_coreRegistry->register('homepageslider_post', $post);
            }
        }

        $resultPage = $this->getResultPage();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Image Information'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
    public function getResultPage()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_resultPage)) {
            $this->_resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        }
        return $this->_resultPage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this to get current admin details :-

```
$this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();//get admin username
$this->authSession->getUser()->getEmail();//get admin email
```

To save admin username in database change controller file of save action to below

```
<?php

namespace OX\HomeSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    )
    {
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $postModel = $this->_objectManager->create('OX\HomeSlider\Model\Post');

        if ($id) {
            $postModel = $postModel->load($id);
        }
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getParam('general');
        $user = $this->getCurrentUser();
        $post['username'] = $user;
        if (empty($post['id'])) {
            $post['id'] = null;
        }

        if (isset($post['image'])) {
            $post['image'] = $post['image'][0]['name'];
        } else {
            $post['image'] = null;
        }


        $postModel->setData($post);
        $postModel->save();
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('homeslider/post/index');
    }
    public function getCurrentUser()
    {
        return $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
    }

}
```

Comment: Then how to save this user name in to DB

Comment: where you want to save username of admin ?

Comment: In my custom table which is stored in DB

Comment: `$username = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
$model = $this->modelnameFactory->create();
$model->setUsername($username);
$model->save();`

Comment: See my updated post.

Comment: can you please add controller file of save action ?

Comment: Thank you admin name successfully saved in DB. But how to dispaly it in admin grid

Comment: do you have display any data in admin grid?